# Convert a fixed length file to csv file

Tags: unix, csv, awk, sed

How can i :

1. Convert a fixed length file to a csv file.
2. Split records from input file (fixed length file) as per the column length.

I have tried to convert the file using **'awk'** however, the result is incorrect due to the spaces in records.

**Input file:**

```
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 12345671LSN12301630 00000000000091640
00409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 12345671LSN12301630 00000000000091640
00409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 12345671LSN12301630 00000000000091640
00409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 12345671LSN12301630 00000000000091640
00409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 12345671LSN12301630 00000000000091640
004009164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 12345671LSN12301630 00000000000091640
004009164
```

> The first record starts from **4002000W1ABCDABCD7821** and ends at
>   **00409164**
>
> There are 6 records in total.

Input file contains 6 records for the table.

There are more than 40 columns in the record, I have mentioned only a few of them.

Columns are fixed length as follows:

```
ABC_ID(9), def_sc(8), sde_hd(8),mln_hfg(12), ghi_jkl(13),ijk_klm(6),pqr_xyz(10)
```

Expected output is as follows:

**Output file:**

```
ABC_ID,     def_sc, sde_hd,   mln_hfg,        ghi_jkl,     ijk_klm,  pqr_xyz
4002000W1, ABCDABCD,78211234, 56702291LSN1, 2301630000000, 000916, 4000409164
4002000W1, ABCDABCD,78211234, 56702291LSN1, 2301630000000, 000916, 4000409164
4002000W1, ABCDABCD,78211234, 56702291LSN1, 2301630000000, 000916, 4000409164
4002000W1, ABCDABCD,78211234, 56702291LSN1, 2301630000000, 000916, 4000409164
4002000W1, ABCDABCD,78211234, 56702291LSN1, 2301630000000, 000916, 4000409164
4002000W1, ABCDABCD,78211234, 56702291LSN1, 2301630000000, 000916, 4000409164
```

Is this possible to achieve using sed command.

Please suggest.

Comment: Please edit your input file data using code tags `{}` like I did on output file. Remove all `>` in the input file.

Comment: at which character does "56789071......" stop?. You need 4 columns or six column for the six records?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you want but GNU awk for FIELDWIDTHS and multi-char RS is one option:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v FIELDWIDTHS="9 8 8 8" -v OFS=', ' '{gsub(/\n/,""); print $1, $2, $3, $4}' file
4002000W1, ABCDABCD, 78211234, 56789071
```

Comment: But when i use the above command on my input file,i am getting the output as : 4002000W1ABCDABCD7821, 123456789071001080600W1VUF34216002902291LSN12301630, 0000000004000000000000009164000400000091645012500000000. Instead of delimiting the record as per the length specified,white spaces are getting replaced by ','. This is not the expected result actually.

Comment: @user229691 Which version of `awk` are you using?

Comment: @user229691 I think you have to install `gawk` to use `FIELDWIDTHS`

Comment: Thanks @HåkonHægland, installing "gawk" works, however it reads a single record from the input file.Rest of the records are not being read.

Comment: It reads the whole file as a single record and splits it into fixed-width fields because that's what your original question indicated (to me at least) that you wanted. Looks like you've significantly modified your question now so hopefully one of the other answers guessed right.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="9 8 8 12 13 6 10" 'NR%2{temp=$0;next;} {$0=temp$0; gsub(/ /,""); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' OFS=','  file
```

#### Input file:

```
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 123456702291LSN1230 16300000000009164
000409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 123456702291LSN1230 16300000000009164
000409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 123456702291LSN1230 16300000000009164
000409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 123456702291LSN1230 16300000000009164
000409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 123456702291LSN1230 16300000000009164
000409164
4002000W1ABCDABCD7821 123456702291LSN1230 16300000000009164
000409164
```

#### Out file:

```
4002000W1,ABCDABCD,78211234,56702291LSN1,2301630000000,000916,4000409164
4002000W1,ABCDABCD,78211234,56702291LSN1,2301630000000,000916,4000409164
4002000W1,ABCDABCD,78211234,56702291LSN1,2301630000000,000916,4000409164
4002000W1,ABCDABCD,78211234,56702291LSN1,2301630000000,000916,4000409164
4002000W1,ABCDABCD,78211234,56702291LSN1,2301630000000,000916,4000409164
4002000W1,ABCDABCD,78211234,56702291LSN1,2301630000000,000916,4000409164
```

For adding the first row just print it in first of all inside `BEGIN{...}`:

```
awk -v FIELDWIDTHS="9 8 8 12 13 6 10" 'BEGIN{print "ABC_ID,    def_sc,   sde_hd,   mln_hfg,        ghi_jkl,     ijk_klm,  pqr_xyz"} NR%2{temp=$0;next;} {$0=temp$0; gsub(/ /,""); print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7}' OFS=','  file
```

#### Explanation:

- `FIELDWIDTHS="9 8 8 12 13 6 10"` specifies length of the fields to print.
- `NR%2{temp=$0;next;}` store odd line in `temp` variable(will be use to join the pair of lines)
- `$0=temp$0` joins each consecutive lines. `$0` is current line and `temp` is line before current line.
- `gsub(/ /,"");` removes space characters.
- `print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,$6,$7` prints the seven fields with predefined widths by `FIELDWIDTHS`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fmt = (9, 8, 8, 12, 13, 6, 10);
my @head = qw(ABC_ID def_sc sde_hd mln_hfg ghi_jkl ijk_klm pqr_xyz);

my $rec_len = do { my $sum; for(@fmt) { $sum += $_ }; $sum };

my $fn = 'file';
open(my $fh, '<', $fn) or die "Could not open file '$fn': $!\n";
my $str = do {local $/ = undef; <$fh>};
close($fh);
$str =~ s/\s*//g;
my $regex = join ("", map { "(.{$_})" } @fmt);

my $head_fmt = join (", ", map { "%-". $_ . "s", } @fmt) . "\n";
printf $head_fmt, @head;

while ( $str =~ /(.{$rec_len})/g ) {
    my @f = $1 =~ /$regex/;
    print join(", ", @f) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
ABC_ID   , def_sc  , sde_hd  , mln_hfg     , ghi_jkl      , ijk_klm, pqr_xyz   
4002000W1, ABCDABCD, 78211234, 5671LSN12301, 6300000000000, 009164, 0004091644
002000W1A, BCDABCD7, 82112345, 671LSN123016, 3000000000000, 091640, 0040916440
02000W1AB, CDABCD78, 21123456, 71LSN1230163, 0000000000000, 916400, 0409164400
2000W1ABC, DABCD782, 11234567, 1LSN12301630, 0000000000009, 164000, 4091644002
000W1ABCD, ABCD7821, 12345671, LSN123016300, 0000000000091, 640004, 0091644002
```

Comment: thanks for the script @Hakon, but i need to do it in shell or gawk.